# When i query facebook events with FQL and i want to get only future events do i have to convert the current time to PST?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I know that when i retrieve data from facebook events it comes in PST time, but when i do a query like this

```
        $imploded_eids = implode( ',', $eids );
        $fql[$id] = "
        SELECT
            eid,
            name,
            description,
            start_time,
            end_time,
            venue,
            location,
            update_time
        FROM
            event
        WHERE
            eid IN ($imploded_eids) AND start_time > $start_time";
```

do i need to convert actual gmt() time to PST time?Or should i use the timezone of the currently logged on user?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to manually populate `$start_time`, your desired time should be entered as America/Los_Angeles (with daylight savings if applicable) and then be converted to UTC for the query. This is true regardless of the events location.

If you are showing times for something like a webinar to users in multiple time zones, you'll take the converted America/Los_Angeles time and treat this as the event locale's time zone. Then convert to a user's current time zone.

From the changes that have occurred to the events dialog over the past few weeks, it looks like how this works is about to change.